# Low toilet water when neighbor flushes

Tags: plumbing

Help!!   I live in a condo.  Since my neighbors renovated their downstairs bathroom, which is next to mine,  whenever they flush the water is siphoned out of my toilet bowl.  It never happened before.  I spoke to them twice about it, asking that they call the installer to see if it was properly installed, but I got no where.
I called our condo management who had their plumber come. He checked the line and removed a big clog, but said that the vent was clear. 
They are telling me that now I need to get a new toilet because the neighbors toilet is the new efficiency model with a strong flush,  yet they told me that may not make a difference. I can't understand why I would have to put in a new toilet because my neighbor renovated???   And to be told it may not solve the problem anyway.  This makes no sense to me. 
I still feel their toilet was improperly installed, but of course I have no proof of that.
I'm concerned about the water getting so low that sewer gases may come into my unit!  Please help!

Comment: When they renovated did they remove a vertical vent or remove a connection to such a vent?

Comment: Thank you for your response.. I am sure you are correct, but how can I find out ?  The neighbors are not very cooperative.

Comment: There is the possibility that the vent pipe is still there but that it is too small of diameter for the new setup. If indeed the neighbors new toilet is one that forcefully flushes very fast it could create a suction to the OPs toilet due to the vent pipe being too small of diameter.

Comment: Thank you. How does one find out if this is what is happening?

Comment: even with your issue, the water should not get so low that gasses enter your apt under normal use

Comment: Thank you . I was concerned  that if I went away for a few days the water would get so low and that would happen..

Comment: are you professional licensed plumbers replying?

Answer (score 1):

I'm with Mr Stewart on this one. I have no doubt, a vent has been disconnected.

You are correct in assuming their remodel, no matter what toilet they use, should never affect the performance of your toilet. That's a ridiculous suggestion.

Comment: Thank you. I thought it absurd that their toilet should affect mine, and am relieved to hear you say it too!  The condo plumber, (who I have used to replace faucets in the past)  is the one who told me to put a new toilet!  I appreciate your response. Now I just have to figure out what to do about it..

Comment: I don't see how a new toilet could solve this problem. All these toilets have a water seal reservoir which would be depleted by suction as easily as your existing toilet. The difference in these newer toilets is in the flushing mechanism.

Comment: I am not a plumber and while I know nothing about plumbing, common sense told me that a new toilet would not fix anything if the real problem(their toilet installation)  was not corrected.  How low is too low for the water in the toilet?  I left it for 5 days to see how low it would go but am afraid of sewer gases....  Guess I need to find another plumber who will stand by this.

Comment: I am not a plumber and yet common sense told me that me getting a new toilet would not correct the situation, only cost me money and still have the same issue.  So, I guess I need to get a plumber in here to tell them it is there toilet, or small claims court :(